# Change non English OS to only output English in Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, maya

I have a Win 7 Korean Edition (its korean edition, not ultimate with language pack).  I am getting this error in Maya when i try to import PyQt4:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

Error: Error in  maya.utils._guiExceptHook:
File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2012\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\utils.py", line 282, in formatGuiException
exceptionMsg = unicode(exceptionObject.args[0])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So on my english win7 this doesnt happen.  I have been reading through the questions on here and some sites on the unicode in python.  I realize this kind of problem should be handled somewhere, but I didnt write the libraries so nothing I can do about it now.

I am assuming this error is from the language of the OS, if so, is it possible to fix this?  My Maya version is in english, but something else seems to be happening in korean?

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using [`sys.setdefaultencoding`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setdefaultencoding). To use it, you'll probably have to put a call to it in your `site.py` or `sitecustomize.py` files, because as the documentation states:

> Once used by the `site` module, it is removed from the `sys` module’s namespace.

I'd first try `utf-8`, since `C1` is a valid UTF-8 start byte and UTF-8 would make sense. If that doesn't work, then I think there's a few Korean-specific encodings, but unfortunately, I don't know much about them. If UTF-8 doesn't work, [this list of encodings supported by Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) suggests that you may want to try `euc_kr`, `iso2022_kr`, `cp949`, `johab`, or `iso2022_jp_2`.